# SQL Get distinct record for each request

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Lets say I have 10 records in the table.

- Id   Name
- 1    abc
- 2    def
- 3    ghi
- 
- 10   xyz

Now there will be multiple request from multiple concurrent request to this SQL table with select top 1 record from this table.

- When First request comes with Select TOP 1 record the first record should be returned and locked for others to update
- When the Second request comes with select TOP 1 record, the next record should be locked and returned
- When the Third request comes with select TOP 1 record, the 3rdrecord should be locked and returned
- 
- When the 10th request comes with select TOP 1 record, the 10th record should be locked and returned

Is there any way to perform this kind of operation?

Comment: Where do the requests come from? Expecting an answer like "10 users with a web page open running an angular app that calls to a back end c# web service, which uses the database"

Comment: for me it looks like queue-implementation. As far as I remember in SQL Server you can use hint READPAST to achieve this

Comment: Do it exactly as you say? Lock the table, pull the first record, set it as in progress, unlock the table?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the inputs. I have an web application and different user or different browser session request number concurrently. I have pre populated the numbers in a SQL table. Now my application layer should get unique number from this SQL table without locking the whole table. If I lock the table it will work but then it will be sequential and impact the performance. 10 was just example I have mentioned but in real it may be thousands. Something similar to http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/ this

Comment: SQL Server 2005 has been unsupported for many **years**.  If you are really using that database, upgrade!  If not, fix the tag.

Comment: SQL server 2005 is not a constraint, I can user latest version may me SQL server 2018 or above as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recommend adding a new column to the table and using the `output` clause.  The new column would be something like `processed_on`.  Then:

```
create table @ids (id int);

update top (1) t with (rowlock)
    set processed_on = getdate()
    output inserted.id into @ids
    where processed_on is null;
```

You want an index on `processed_on`.  I believe this will lock only the row in question.

Then go about processing `@ids`.